# Concatenating and grouping results from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single table with a layout similar to this:

```
code | model | title          | colour
-----|-------|----------------|-------
1001 | 1001  | Product 1 Name | Blue
2001 | 2001  | Product 2 Name | Red
3001 | 3001  | Product 3 Name | Blue
3001 | 3002  | Product 3 Name | Red
3001 | 3003  | Product 3 Name | Green
4001 | 4001  | Product 4 Name | Blue
```

I want to create an HTML via PHP table of results with this output:

```
code | model            | title          | colour
-----|------------------|----------------|-----------------
1001 | 1001             | Product 1 Name | Blue
2001 | 2001             | Product 2 Name | Red
3001 | 3001, 3002, 3003 | Product 3 Name | Blue, Red, Green
4001 | 4001             | Product 4 Name | Blue
```

I have done all the `mysqli` database connection bits and built a query to throw the results out into a table, that's the easy bit, but the concatenation and grouping - I can't figure out how it's done.

I've tried `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` functions but it's not giving me anything I can seem to work with.

Comment: Can you add your query so far? That `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP_BY` wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select code, 
       group_concat(model) as model, 
       title, 
       group_concat(colour) as colour
from your_table
group by code, title
```